# Xorg can't find screens

Tags: nvidia, grub2, graphics, xorg

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. It installed successfully, but whenever I boot into it, after the GRUB screen I get a text TTY. I can log in with that and enter command-line commands.

I have tried:

- running `startx`. After initializing extensions, it tries to load extension GLX and then has a fatal error, "no screens found". **Looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows that "Screen(s) found, but none has a usable configuration."**
- running `sudo Xorg`, which did the same as `startx`.
- removing and reinstalling `xserver-xorg` with `apt-get`. This ran successfully but didn't seem to change anything.
- doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`, which seemed to have no effect and didn't output anything.
- running `gnome-session`, which says that it "could not open X display".
- running `sudo service gdm restart`, which makes the screen flicker a few times and then seems to have no effect.
- looking at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but that turns out to not exist.
- changing the "Configured Video Device" in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` to use `fbdev` instead of `vesa`. This seemed to have no effect.
- removing `~/.Xauthority`, which also seemed to have no effect.

Other relevant facts:

- I added `nomodeset` to the GRUB boot options. Not doing this causes the screen to just go black and stay black.
- The laptop had UEFI which made installing Ubuntu difficult, but that seems to be disabled now.
- **The graphics card is Nvidia GEForce GTX, 670M and 30GB.**

I can't easily post log files here because I have no way of getting them off the computer short of typing them up manually. I'm a newbie, so if there's a workaround please share!

Thanks for all help! :)